# play flv and mkv format video in web page without downloading

Tags: html, mysql, video

I'm developing exam portal site, where faculty upload video tutorials for students. I want to play video when the student click the tutorial without downloading.video include (.flv,.mkv,.mp4) formats
I referred internet but not able to understand please any one help with simple example.
I'm using php and mysql

```
    <html><body><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-hover table-stripped" id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr style="background:lightblue">
                <td align="center">Department Name</td>
                <th  align="center">Video Tutorials</th>
                <th align="center">Action</th>  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
        $query=mysql_query("select * from video_uploads order by id desc");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $name=$row['file'];
            $dept=$row['dept_name'];
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;<?php echo $dept;?>
        </td>
            <td>
            <iframe width="460" height="215" src="staff/video/<?php echo $name ;?>" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
                &nbsp;
            </td>

        </tr>
        <?php }?>       </table></body></html>
```

code for upload video is here

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
 $dept_name=$_POST['dept'];
  $name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
  $size=$_FILES['file']['size'];
  $type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
  $temp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

  move_uploaded_file($temp,"video/".$name);
  $sql="INSERT INTO video_uploads(dept_name,file,type,size) VALUES('$dept_name','$name','$type','$size')";
    if(executeQuery($sql))


    {
    echo "      <script>
    alert('successfully uploaded');
    window.location.href='videoupload.php?success';
    </script>";

    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <script>
    alert('error while uploading file');
    window.location.href='videoupload.php?fail';
    </script>
    <?php
    }
   }  
   ?>
```

Comment: Ther is no support in the video tag for mkv or flv. Only MP4 and ogg and webm. So the fils must be converted.. The files are still downloaded, it just the browser does it for you automatically.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html><body><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-hover table-stripped" id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr style="background:lightblue">
                <td align="center">Department Name</td>
                <th  align="center">Video Tutorials</th>
                <th align="center">Action</th>  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
        $query=mysql_query("select * from video_uploads order by id desc");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $name=$row['file'];
            $dept=$row['dept_name'];
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;<?php echo $dept;?>
        </td>
            <td>

            <video width="460" height="215" >
                 <source src="staff/video/<?php echo $name ;?>" type="videp/mp4" >
            </video>

                &nbsp;
            </td>

        </tr>
        <?php }?>       </table></body></html>
```

If you want to play flv or mkv video then just replace the "mp4" to "mkv" or any video format you want it.

Comment: if i replace it as flv or mkv it is downloading directly. only mp4  video is playing

Comment: I have tested many ways to play video but all that options are become too old so they are not working properly, You can do one more thing is that you should try this method again on another browser or update the existing browser.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The video tag can not play flv or mkv.

Comment: whether in iframe also flv and mkv can not play ?

Comment: i need to play video in web page is there any other way to implement it? If yes means kindly explain me with a simple example

Comment: You can upload video to the youtube and add the youtube uploaded video onto the your website and user can play pause video as we do in youtube